# jQuery-ui removing bottom border

Tags: jquery-ui, border, jquery-ui-tabs

I just created a simple container for 2 tabs using jQuery UI, and all i want to do now is remove a border that appears beneath it. I've tried multiple times using info from similar questions, still nothing. Here's the code being used:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#Tabs").tabs();
});
</script>

<div class="Tabs" id="Tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#Tabs-1">Background</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Tabs-2">Contact Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Tabs-3">Photos</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabContent">

        <div id="Tabs-1">
           Some content
        </div>

        <div id="bgTabs-2">
           Some content
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS being used:

```
div.Tabs {
height: auto;
width: 625px;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;

}

.Tabs ul {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
list-style-type: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.Tabs ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
}

    .Tabs ul li a {
        padding: 0px 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-decoration-color: black;
        text-decoration-style: none;
        border-bottom:none;
    }
```

Even with the "border-bottom:none" line, I keep getting a border. No matter where i placed it. 
I even tried
    .ui-widget-content{
    border: none;
    }

Again, I did search this site, but i figured asking about it in it's most simplest form such as this with this code should be helpful to future references.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your issue will be resolved by using `border:0;` rather than `border:none;`.
Try using something like this:

```
.ui-widget-content {
    border-bottom:0;
}
```

or like this:

```
.ui-widget-content {
    border:0;
}
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/YLHb4/)**

Comment: This affects all objects with ui-widget-content. Unacceptable.